# BEM Global modifier for color

Tags: css, sass, styles, bem

I've been using BEM for a week, and there is a thing I don't get.

BEM says global modifiers are not recommended (http://getbem.com/faq/#can-i-create-global-modifier)

But then how should I do this ?

**global scss** (shared classes)

```
@each $green in $primary-greens {
  .primary-green-#{index($primary-greens, $green)} {
    color: $green;
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-icon svgIcon=check-circle class="primary-green-4"></mat-icon>
```

In BEM how to do this ? I should do this ? But then it means duplicate the same code everywhere for each green icon ?

**component.html**

```
<mat-icon svgIcon=check-circle class="icon--green"></mat-icon>
```

**component.scss**

```
.icon--green {
  color: list.nth($primary-greens, 3);
}
```

Comment: BEM is just a methodology, you can tweak it to make it work for you. Many frontend frameworks have color utility classes like `bg-green` which is fine if you prefer to use those. That guide is mostly taking about specificity, but if you don't use color css in the blocks then you wont have that issue.

Comment: @dantheman I agree that this is a methodology but I was looking for "the proper way" to achieve this AND respect BEM

Answer (score 0):

In the BEM methodology this is not a global modifier but a block. You can use your class `primary-green-4`.